# How to handle a button click in Django project?

Tags: django

I have a form as below:

```
<form action="{% url clicked %}" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Button" name="btn"/>
</form>
```

`url`:

```
 url(r'^clicked/$', views.button_clicked, name='clicked'),
```

Whenever I click on the button, it should redirect to another page and return json file.

```
def button_clicked(request):
    if request.GET.get('btn'):
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/clicked/')

    to_json = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

I'm wondering if this the best approach to deal with the problem above.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Do you **not** want to redirect?

Comment: The button is not responding when I click on it.

Comment: Well of course not. Your form action is null.

Comment: I've changed the action. it still not responding. do I actually need javascript to handle button clicked?

Comment: No. I think you need to update your question with exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Right now, it doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Replace `type="button"` with `type="submit"`